# Is there any systemic way to find the minimum access right or role required for each of Azure CLI commands?

Tags: azure-cli

I am working on a project in which I need to define the exact minimum security role for each operation.

Is there any systemic way or documentation to find the minimum access right or role required for each of Azure CLI commands?

Comment: Not for CLI commands, but to find minimum permission required to deploy and ARM template you can look at https://github.com/maniSbindra/az-mpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is no systemic way or doc to find it directly, it needs some experience and test, you could refer to the things below, it applies to most situations.

Azure CLI commands essentially call the [Azure REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/), you could use `--debug` parameter with a CLI command, then you can find the API the command calls.

For example, I use the `az vm list` to list all the VMs in a resource group.

```
az vm list -g <group-name> --debug
```

[image]

Then you will find it calls [Virtual Machines - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachines/list) API, then you can search for the resource provider and resource type i.e. `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines` in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations), easily we can find `Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/read`, here you need some experience, from my sight,  the action permission should be correct.

[image]

Then you can create a [custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles) with this action to have a test, and change the permissions depend on the result, in most situations, the command will include the action permission you need in the error message if you don't have enough permissions to do the operations.

Comment: Any equivalent trick for Microsoft Graph?